# где здесь коллизия?

Tags: сеть, vlan, коллизии

топология такая :
[image: .]

с порта ge1 генератора трафика поступает трафик в заголовке source MAC-адрес device2, а в destination MAC-адрес порта ge0 генератора трафика.
Физически трафик с 45 vlan генерится с порта ge1, далее через коммутатор передаётся device 1, device1 передает его device2 по радиосвязи, и device2 обратно возвращает его в генератор трафика на порт ge0 :

[image: .]

Управление device1 с ПК происходит по 30 vlan, проходя через две сети между которыми создан маршрут и коммутатор. Управление device2 передается по радиосвязи от device1.

При запуске трафика ложится управление device1, но остаётся у device2 (хотя второму устройству трафик с 30 vlan (управлением) передаётся по радиоканалу). Устройства перестают пинговаться, хотя связь по радио у них остаётся.
В итоге трафик между устройствами идет и по 45, и по 30 влану.
Замечались в небольшом количестве ошибки в контрольной последовательности кадров.

**Если трафик с генератора погасить, то точно также не будет управление с ПК устройствами, но если пингануть с первого устройства второе - пойдут пинги с ПК на первое устройство.**
Duplex mismatch исключен, полный дуплекс и отключено автосогласование.

для понятности, вланы расположены так...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу разобраться, почему при такой топологии пропадает управление device1 и пинг между устройствами. Если есть варианты попробовать утилиты диагностики и др. - пишите, буду рада...

Comment: на device1 vlan 30 в tagged на портах ge0, управление и radio;
на device2 vlan 30 в tagged управление и radio;
а свитч не управляемый

Comment: неуправляемый свитч D-Link заменила на управляемый SNR. Нет MAC-flapping, переполнения таблицы маков, ошибок на интерфейсах.
Чудеса...